# SQL Query not searching data if record contains zero

Tags: sql, select, join

I have two tables and with column paperNo and some data regarding that paper. I am trying to search all data based on paper no. from both the tables. I have successfully written the query and it is retrieving the data successfully. but I have noticed that. If my paperNo contains zero(0) then the query is not searching for that data. And for the non zero contains paperNo it is retrieving the same record twice.

I don't understand what is going wrong. tried every thing.

Here is my Query .-

```
SELECT PaperDate.paperNo,
       PaperDate.RAW_PAPER,
       PaperDate.EDGE_SEALED,
       PaperDate.HYDRO_120,
       PaperDate.HYDRO_350,
       PaperDate.CATALYST_1ST,
       PaperDate.CATALYST_2ND,
       PaperDate.SIC_350,
       tblThicknessPaperDate.rawThickness,
       tblThicknessPaperDate.catThickness,
       tblThicknessPaperDate.sicThickness,
       tblThicknessPaperDate.rejectedThickness
FROM tblThicknessPaperDate
FULL OUTER JOIN PaperDate ON PaperDate.paperNo =tblThicknessPaperDate.paperNo
WHERE (tblThicknessPaperDate.paperNo = @paperNo)
```

Comment: Why do you need full outer join?

Comment: I want data from both tables. other joins are not getting data if the record for the particular paperNo is not present in 1st table.

Comment: ...because of your WHERE clause?

Comment: Do I need to change my where clause?

Comment: And why I am getting two records ?

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
FROM tblThicknessPaperDate
RIGHT JOIN PaperDate ON PaperDate.paperNo =tblThicknessPaperDate.paperNo
WHERE (PaperDate.paperNo = @paperNo)
```

The two changes are: swapping to a right join so even if a record isn't in tblThicknessPaperDate we will still see the record in PaperDate.  The other change is to use PapterDate.paperNo in the where clause.  Since tblThicknessPaperDate.paperNo could be null we don't want to use that in the where if we can avoid it.

Comment: But it won't select the record from tblThicknessPaperDate if the record for that paperNo is presend in PaperData table.

Comment: @user3060948 It should.  The right join means keep all rows from the PaperDate table even if there isn't a match in tblThicknessPaperDate.

Comment: Ok I got it. I have added one more OR condition for PaperDate.paperNo = @paperNo. Which fixed the problem. But still I don't know why I am getting two records for the same entry .

Comment: @user3060948  Are you using the right join or the outer join?  You could add some example data to your question to help us figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PaperDate.paperNo,
       PaperDate.RAW_PAPER,
       PaperDate.EDGE_SEALED,
       PaperDate.HYDRO_120,
       PaperDate.HYDRO_350,
       PaperDate.CATALYST_1ST,
       PaperDate.CATALYST_2ND,
       PaperDate.SIC_350,
       tblThicknessPaperDate.rawThickness,
       tblThicknessPaperDate.catThickness,
       tblThicknessPaperDate.sicThickness,
       tblThicknessPaperDate.rejectedThickness
FROM tblThicknessPaperDate
FULL OUTER JOIN PaperDate ON PaperDate.paperNo =tblThicknessPaperDate.paperNo
WHERE (tblThicknessPaperDate.paperNo = @papNo | PaperDate.paperNo = @paperNo)
```

Comment: You should explain how this solved your problem. And maybe you can also reduce the code to the relevant parts.